# How to get proper soundcloud url for embedding from a standard url?

Tags: php, javascript, soundcloud

So right now I can grab the url from already embedded soundcloud files in embed or iframe tags and use those urls on another page and display it in fancybox. Is there a way to get the right url or display in fancybox if a user offers a typical share url such as `http://soundcloud.com/song-b/song-please` or `http://snd.sc/yp6VMo`? I tried looking at the api documentation but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He is trying to get html to create a Soundcloud widget, not get the API url for a track.  The [oEmbed method](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/oembed) "will serve the widget embed code for any SoundCloud URL pointing to a user, group, set or a playlist" and is recommended to make sure Soundclouds changes don't break your app (as opposed making your own Flash object or iframe).  You can call it with a PHP web request to

```
http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=[escaped_url]&iframe=true
```

Or with a JSON-P call (using jQuery for convenience)

```
$.getJSON('http://soundcloud.com/oembed?callback=?',
    {format: 'js', url: 'http://snd.sc/yp6VMo', iframe: true},
    function(data) {
        // Stick the html content returned in the object into the page
        $('#your_player_div').html(data['html'])
    }
)
```

I'm adding iframe=true so you get the new HTML5 player, omit to get the old Flash object.  It also works with the .sc short urls you are using.

Comment: To adjust the size go to the oEmbed page http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/oembed and use the properties maxwidth and maxheight.

Comment: "is recommended to make sure Soundclouds changes don't break your app", lol, their changes did break this.

Answer (score 8):

you can try this for song url not for the id of song url

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/elissafranceschi/war&auto_play=false&color=915f33&theme_color=00FF00"></iframe>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! That means you don’t need the track ID. Very nice!

Comment: Looks like soundcloud caught on and appears you can't do it like this anymore. Laaaame.

Comment: @SlickRemix I just tried with this `<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/bmsharp/you-and-yours-acle-kahney-remix"></iframe>` and it's working

Answer (score 6):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but it sounds like you might need the "resolve" API endpoint. http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/resolve

Example:

```
$ curl -v 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID'

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json
```

This will give you all the track information and that should be enough for whatever you need to do. Also don't forget that there's the [HTML5 widget](http://blog.soundcloud.com/2012/01/26/html5-widget/) too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, modified code from [here](http://blog.soundcloud.com/2009/07/28/soundcloud-player-in-forums-5-step-guide-for-soundcloud-bb-code/):

```
<object height="81" width="100%">
   <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;g=bb"></param>
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;g=bb" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
</object>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $url; ?></a>
```