# Soundcloud embedding: change in iframe source URI?

Tags: soundcloud, embedding

Until a few days ago, I could just take a Soundcloud link like this one:

`https://soundcloud.com/artist/song-title`

… and put it into an iframe `src` like this:

`//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/artist/song-title`

Now I’m getting an error saying “url parameter is not a valid SoundCloud URL”. The embedding options at any Soundcloud page now show a link built like this:

`https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/12345678`

I couldn’t find any information on a recent change. Does this mean I cannot derive the embedded source from a standard Soundcloud URI? Is there no way around a server-side oEmbed call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that removing 'api.' from the url parameter worked.

Old:

```
//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/(blah blah blah)
```

New:

```
//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//soundcloud.com/(blah blah blah)
```

Comment: Great! Rather simplistic, but I wouldn’t have this one figured out. I wonder if it’s desired by Soundcloud or just a “hidden feature”. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same issue after finding that the SC players on my site no longer worked.
I found the answer here ("Load widgets" section):
http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api

It looks like the url parameter has changed from this structure:

> //w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/

To simply this:

> //api.soundcloud.com/tracks/

Comment: So by removing the plain artist and song names, Soundcloud requires webmasters to use their JavaScript API? Since one cannot longer derive embed code from a copy-pasted link, there’s no way around a widget API call (aside from dropping Soundcloud recognition)… is it?

Comment: There a few ways to use the regular artist/song names.  One is by using the "resolve" endpoint in the API (see here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870270/how-to-get-soundcloud-embed-code-by-soundcloud-com-url?rq=1)).  You can also use the oEmbed API endpoint: [link](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed). The SC API is language agnostic; see examples in Ruby, PHP, Javascript, and Python in the API docs.