# Getting a SoundCloud API client ID

Tags: soundcloud

Encountered a problem accessing my tracks from browser.
Usually i type this link in my browser to access downloadable tracks:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/294324164/download?client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea

But now i can not access it anymore, probably the client id is changed.
How can i obtain a new client id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple.. Go to any tracks that you can download on soundcloud, press f12 and look at networks tab, click download and it will show you something like

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/322109493/download?client_id=2t9loNQH90kzJcsFCODdigxfp325aq4z&oauth_token=2-274121-85658-y9KQYyZ6qG9oT2uvPq

Grab that client_id, replace it and amend the url from download? to stream?.. use streams? if you want a list of urls in json format

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/294324164/stream?client_id=2t9loNQH90kzJcsFCODdigxfp325aq4z

Comment: Unfortunately now almost every track than can be downloaded links to an external site...

Answer (score 6):

As no one else has mentioned it, in a Chrome-based browser under DevTools <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, you can grab your `client_id` from the Network tab on reload. Many items listed here reference the SoundCloud API and require your `client_id` to access it. Simply click any item in the list that isn't an `image/base64` item (preferably something that begins with `id?...`), then check the `Request URL` for a `client_id`.

It's the simplest way to grab the ID; now that you know how, don't do anything illegal k thx.

For those thinking this is the same as the other answer mentioning a download link, this method skips that entirely as many songs are no longer available from SoundCloud itself, but from external sources that are linked instead.

Amazing it's been this long, yet there's no "public" Soundcloud API. I'm amazed to find something worse off than the Twitch API.

Answer (score 4):

See this user's solution for a way to do this without a CLIENT ID which you can no longer get from soundcloud: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27461646/179571

Answer (score 1):

`youtube-dl https://soundcloud.com/my-fav-artist`
seems to work and pull all tracks as mp3
no client_id needed, if you needed the client_id to get something
like `soundcloud-dl` to work

Answer (score -3):

You can apply for a client ID by filling in the [SoundCloud Application Registration form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/viewform).

Comment: Soundcloud no longer be processing API application requests. as you can see at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform

Comment: Doesn't make this a wrong answer, because that should be the right way..

Comment: Is there perhaps an alternate way to get a client ID?

Comment: @PetrusTheron I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244969/upload-songs-audio-files-to-a-specific-soundcloud-account-using-soundcloud-api?noredirect=1#comment99109484_56244969) I am wondering if you can have a look.