# How to get iTunes embed code by itunes.apple.com URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, itunes

I have been researching for hours with no luck to get it worked. I want to get embed this URL https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/luys-i-luso/1035022308

like this

I want for iTunes as here did for SoundCloud

[How to get Soundcloud embed code by soundcloud.com url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870270/how-to-get-soundcloud-embed-code-by-soundcloud-com-url)

Comment: Umm...like what?

Comment: Like this inside iframe there is a URL https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/101276036


<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/101276036&amp;color=ff6600&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get id in URL and set in embed like this

`<iframe src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=us&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=music&e=album&w=250&h=300&ids=279589427&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:250px;height: 300px;border:0px"></iframe>`